# How to use the remainder operator

Tags: java, operators

Currently I am working with the % operator in Java. I thought I understood it but after coming across this question am now confused. So I know that 10 % 3 = Remainder 1. My question is why would 3 % 8 = Remainder 3 I thought that this would instead equal 0 because 3 goes into 8 zero times? Another example would be 2 % 8 = Remainder 2 why would this ones remainder not be zero also? If someone could explain why this is that would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Other way around, `8` goes into `3` zero times, leaving a remainder of `3`. `%` is complimentary to `/` (or division). `2 / 8` is `0`, so the remainder is the original value (or `2`). For the remainder to be `0`, the number must be divisible by `8`. So, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, etc.

Comment: _3 goes into 8 zero times_ isnt true 3 goes into 8 twice. Your thinking about it backwards. 8 goes into 3 zero times and we still have our 3 leftover

Comment: It's not a modulus operator. It is a *remainder* operator.

Comment: 10 % 3 is equivalent to asking what's the remainder after we fit as many 3's into 10 as possible, we can fit 3 3's into 10 which is 9. The remainder is equal to 10 - 3*3 which is 1. Now if we reverse the roles and do 3 % 10 we can't fit a single 10 into 3 so our remainder is 3 - 0*10 which is 3

Comment: I remembered it this way, N % 2 = 0 ? even: odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct behavior, mathematically speaking.

Hopefully people will indulge me a digression, but the integers mod n are all of the integers from 0 to `n - 1`. They form a [multiplicative group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) that's important to number theory and cryptography. In fact, if you do

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(i % n);
}
```

this will give you all the numbers from 0 to (n - 1) over and over again, just like the group.

Without going into details, a [mathematical group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) is a set with an operation that behaves more or less like you'd expect it to with "ordinary" arithmetic. For example, if a set forms a group under multiplication, that means that multiplication "works" for that set.

If `n` is the power of a prime (e.g. 32), then the integers mod n form a [finite field](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), meaning that it behaves quite a bit like ordinary arithmetic.

**TL;DR** This behavior is by design. It's actually mathematically perfectly correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

The remainder operator is explained in the Java tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

If you are looking for a modulo operator, then use `Math.floorMod` at it treats negative numbers as you'd expect. The documentation gives examples of the difference between `%` and `floorMod`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-